# C++ Get Current date output weird result

Tags: c++

My output is unreadable, all i wanted to do is assign the day month year into a string.

if i cout them by now->tm_year+1900 , it works, but if i assign it to a string and cout later, it output like this. how do i change my code so i can assign the value to string without losing reference later on cout.

Terminal:

```
Date is
```

My code:

```
int main()
{
//get today date
string year,month,day;

/* Output 6 month frame for appointment booking*/
 time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
 struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

year = now->tm_year + 1900;
month = now->tm_mon + 1;
day = now->tm_mday;

cout << "Date is " << year << month << day << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign integers to strings (well, you can, but it doesn't quite do what you'd expect); you have to convert them first:

```
std::string year = std::to_string(now->tm_year + 1900);
```

Other options include storing the number as an integer; you can print integers, too:

```
int year = now->tm_year + 1900;
```

Comment: Okay i understand now. It was wrong data type that i use, using int fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: if this answer was helpful to you, please mark your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `int` instead of `string` in your code file.